# Why do implicit conversions not work for out-of-line operators on a template class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I tried writing a class with operators two different ways.  First, I tried it with the operators defined inside the class.  Then, I tried it with the operators defined outside the class.  Defining the operators outside the class appears to be better because I can take advantage of implicit conversions on the left-hand-operand.  It appears to be widely recommended that operators be defined outside the class when possible.

However, when I make the class a template class, implicit conversions on the left-hand-operand no longer work.  In fact, implicit conversions on the right-hand-operand also do not work.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
namespace N1 {
template <class T>
class C1 {
 public:
  double value;
  /* implicit */ C1(double value) : value{value} {}
  C1(const C1<T>& other) : value{other.value} {}
  C1<T>& operator=(const C1<T>& other) {
    this->value = other.value;
    return *this;
  }
  // Define operator+ for C1 inline
  inline C1<T> operator+(const C1<T>& other) const {
    return this->value + other.value;
  }
};

template <class T>
class C2 {
 public:
  double value;
  /* implicit */ C2(double value) : value{value} {}
  C2(const C2<T>& other) : value{other.value} {}
  C2<T>& operator=(const C2<T>& other) {
    this->value = other.value;
    return *this;
  }
};
// Define operator+ for C2 out-of-line
template <class T>
inline C2<T> operator+(const C2<T>& self, const C2<T>& other) {
  return self.value + other.value;
}
} // namespace N1

namespace {
using C1 = N1::C1<int>;
using C2 = N1::C2<int>;

// double f1(double x, const C1& y) {
//   return (x + y).value; // not expected to work
// }
double f2(const C1& x, double y) {
  return (x + y).value; // works
}
double f3(double x, const C2& y) {
  // Works when C2 is a class, fails when C2 is a template class
  return (x + y).value;
}
double f4(const C2& x, double y) {
  // Works when C2 is a class, fails when C2 is a template class
  return (x + y).value;
}
} // namespace
```

my hope is that clients should be able to write code such as

```
void my_main() {
  N1::C2<Anything> x{4};
  auto y = x + 2.0;
  auto z = 2.0 + x;
}
```

Comment: There are no parts missing.  This is a complete repro of the issue.  The `+` operator in functions `f3` and `f4` do not compile.  The conversion from `double` is not being considered.

Comment: Implicit conversions are never considered on function parameters which deduce a template argument.

Comment: Btw: you could define a operator at namespace scope inside the class body to avoid having to use `template...` again: `friend C1 operator=(C1 const& o1, C1 const& o2) { ... }`

Comment: What is the template parameter used for? The contained type is always `double` so that part is a bit unclear.

Comment: It isn't relevant to the question, but imagine that this class is used for imaginary numbers, and the type parameter defines what type is used to represent the real and imaginary components (it could be float, or double, or extended precision).  I'm actually using it for dual numbers to automatically compute derivatives.

Comment: What `operator+` should return? A value? A class? What type for `auto` in `auto r= x +2` is expected?

Comment: Some people insist that implicit conversions are not a feature of C++, but rather a *bug*. They would suggest that `x + 2.0` is confusing and `x + N1::C2<Anything>{2.0}` is the way to go. They would disallow things like `1 + 2.0` if they could. Their position is not unreasonable, so it's just something to consider.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix `C1`'s first test case by adding the out of line `operator+`

```cpp
template<class T>
C1<T> operator+(double d, const C1<T>& c1) {
    return c1 + d;
}
```

to get both test cases to pass:

```cpp
double f1(double x, const C1& y) {
   return (x + y).value; // not expected to work - but now works
}
double f2(const C1& x, double y) {
    return (x + y).value;  // works
}
```

---

The C2 tests: To fix those, you need to make `N1::C2<int>` a dependent type. You can do that with a bit of SFINAE which considers *all* `N1::C2<T>`s, but only accepts it when `T` is `int`. Note that it's a problem with the test cases - not with implicit conversion.

```cpp
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T,int>, double>
f3(double x, const N1::C2<T>& y) {
    return (x + y).value; // implicit conversion works
}

template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T,int>, double>
f4(const N1::C2<T>& x, double y) {
    return (x + y).value; // implicit conversion works
}
```

or using your `C2` typedef which makes it consider *all* `T`'s but only accepts `N1::C2<int>`:

```cpp
using C2 = N1::C2<int>;

template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T,C2>, double>
f3(double x, const T& y) {
    return (x + y).value; // implicit conversion works
}

template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T,C2>, double>
f4(const T& x, double y) {
    return (x + y).value; // implicit conversion works
}
```

In the comments you say you want the functions to accept *all* `N1::C2<T>`s and then it becomes simpler:

```cpp
template<class T>
auto f3(double x, const N1::C2<T>& y) {
    return (x + y).value;
}

template<class T>
auto f4(const N1::C2<T>& x, double y) {
    return (x + y).value;
}
```

- *My hope is that clients can write code such as ... Is that not possible?*

  ```
  N1::C2<int> x{4};

  auto y = x + 2.0;
  auto z = 2.0 + x;
  ```

Yes, but you then need to add overloads for that:

```cpp
template <class T>
C2<T> operator+(const C2<T>& lhs, double rhs) {
    return lhs.value + rhs;
}

template <class T>
C2<T> operator+(double lhs, const C2<T>& rhs) {
    return rhs + lhs; // just swapped the order to use the above
}
```

---

Another option, which is how it's commonly done, is to add the `operator+=` member function:

```cpp
template<class T>
class C2 {
// ...
    C2& operator+=(const C2& other) {
        value += other.value;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

You could then define the free functions like so:

```cpp
template <class T>
C2<T> operator+(const C2<T>& lhs, std::convertible_to<C2<T>> auto&& rhs) {
    auto rv = lhs;
    rv += rhs;
    return rv;
}

template <class T, class U>
std::enable_if_t<!std::same_as<std::decay_t<U>*, C2<T>*>, C2<T>>
operator+(const U& lhs, const C2<T>& rhs) {
    return rhs + lhs;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vaxq56o3c)

Instead of SFINAE as above, you could create a home made `concept` to avoid ambiguity when adding two `C2<T>`s:

```
template <class From, class To>
concept convertible_to_but_is_not =
    not std::same_as<std::remove_reference_t<From>, To> &&
    std::convertible_to<From, To>;

template <class T>
C2<T> operator+(const C2<T>& lhs, std::convertible_to<C2<T>> auto&& rhs) {
    auto rv = lhs;
    rv += rhs;
    return rv;
}

template <class T> // making sure that lhs is not a C2<T>
C2<T> operator+(convertible_to_but_is_not<C2<T>> auto&& lhs, const C2<T>& rhs) {
    return rhs + lhs;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EW781ozzM)

Comment: I want code such as `f3` and `f4` to work for all instantiations of `C2`, not just `C2<int>`.  I also don't want to force authors of code such as `f3` and `f4` to go through these gyrations.  From the point of view of end-users of these types, the conversions should just work (i.e. they should just be able to add a double to any instantiation of C2).

Comment: @NealGafter Ok, but you've type defined  `C2 = N1::C2<int>` and used that in your tests.  so how did you expect any of them to accept a `N1::C2<float>`? I updated the answer.

Comment: My hope is that clients can write code such as
`
void my_main() {
  N1::C2<int> x{4};
  auto y = x + 2.0;
  auto z = 2.0 + x;
}
`
Is that not possible?

Comment: @NealGafter Yes, I updated the answer - and added an alternative

Comment: @NealGafter Did you try one of the alternatives I added? Both `x + 2.0`, `2.0 + x` and also `x + y` works.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Ted's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73560249/241658):

Implicit conversions are not considered from function arguments during [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions).  This problem can be addressed by the addition of two helper functions:

```
template <class T>
inline C2<T> operator+(double self, const C2<T>& other) {
  return self + other.value;
}
template <class T>
inline C2<T> operator+(const C2<T>& self, double other) {
  return self.value + other;
}
```